# Spring WebServiceTemplate sending the request using POST method of HTTP protocol

Tags: spring, web-services, soap

```
2016-09-23 16:42:15,439 DEBUG uid={4}RMI TCP Connection(14)-10.83.14.125 - httpclient.wire.header:70 - >> "POST /MyProject/hello1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
```

I am trying to write a client for reading the SOAP web services. I am using spring WebServiceTemplate & CommonsHttpMessageSender for basic authentication. But getting the below error -

```
"Could not retrieve WSDL for"
```

Is any one know how i can send the message using GET method of HTTP Protocol? 
Thanks in advance.

```
  <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="URL"/>
```

`<property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
            <property name="credentials">
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
                    <constructor-arg value="username"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="password"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    </bean>`

Comment: Can you please add your configuration?

Comment: done please check

Comment: what is the value of "URL" ? is it referencing bean or just string ?

Comment: I am hitting WSDL

Comment: Please make sure you can access the wsdl link in browser and also please add  the stacktrace leading to that error. I'm not entiely sure but when using web service template you just need to provide uri of the service not the wsdl uri.

Comment: I am able to access WSDL from browser and SoapUI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124042/discussion-between-reddy-and-aashutosh-shrivastava).